# How to create dynamic mailto link with subject as entry title

Tags: email, title, formatting

I am managing careers on a client's website, and am trying to properly add a mailto link below each career description with an email address from one of the publish fields, as well as adding the subject to be the entry title of the career. I can't figure out how to properly format the entry title with %20 instead of a space. How can I do this? Here is my current code:

```
<p><em>Applicants should email resumés to <a href="{mailto_email}" target="blank">{mailto_email}</a>.</em></p>
```

The client wants the email address to be displayed (not encoded), so I am just displaying everything as default. I'm assuming my code will look something like the following, but with the entry title formatted somehow:

```
<p><em>Applicants should email resumés to <a href="{mailto_email}?subject={title}" target="blank">{mailto_email}</a>.</em></p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use an [available plugin](https://github.com/juddlyon/ee-url-encoder) to encode things for URLs. I haven't tried or used this plugin, but I think the syntax would be something like this:

```
<a href="{mailto_email}?subject={exp:url_encoder method='rawurlencode'}{title}{/exp:url_encoder}" target="blank">
```

As a last resort, you could also use PHP and run `rawurlencode()` on it, like so:

```
<a href="{mailto_email}?subject=<?=rawurlencode("{title}")?>" target="blank">
```

Remember PHP should be set to parse on the output stage.

Comment: The plugin encodes the title with "+" instead of "%20" (which is supposed to be safer then "+") but this will work. Thank you! I used the 'urlencode' method instead of 'rawurlencode' for the plugin, in case you decide to try it out yourself sometime.

Comment: Since in this case it's part of the query string (part of the URI after the `?`), `+` is both safe and correct. (See "Query Strings" in the [W3 URI specification](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html).